# Model Decks for Game of Thrones The Card Game?

Tags: deck-building, game-of-thrones-card-game

I've recently bought the game of thrones card game, and a group of friends and I enjoyed playing the core game so much we've bought all the basic house expansions.

I don't think any of our players are going to be that much into deck building, but I'd like to  make it so that we have a set of decks (Maybe two for each house) that can provide variety while being balanced.

We didn't mind playing with the decks that came with the game out of the box, but that doesn't incorporate houses Greyjoy or Martell, and when I was playing Martell last night I noticed that quite a few of the cards in the deck that comes out of the box weren't house Martell at all so I would have had to pay extra to play them. (I just unwrapped one of the 3 sets in the expansion because we wanted to get started ASAP.)

Are there any lists of Model decks for each house using the core cards and the cards in the house expansions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick search and came up with two good resources for this. [First](http://elitistjerks.com/blogs/122150-emptyrepublic/566-building_game_thrones_lcg_deck/), some general guidelines for building cohesive decks that can work from ElitistJerks.com. The article lays out quite a bit of good information about this process that will probably help in determining how to create your decks.

[Second](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/GoTDecks.html), I found a website where players can post decks they have built. Other players can then rate the decks so you could get a feel for what people think is good (although most decks seem to go unrated as of right now). Each deck page has a list of cards in it, the description and how it is suppose to play, and other statistics on deck composition. The site is divided into each of the six houses, along with a list for neutral decks. This seems to be the best list for what you're doing, since you can focus on one house list and then move to the next when you're done.

Comment: The second one sounds good. I'll wait to see if anyone else comes up with anything else and if not I'll mark you as the correct answer.